# Adding columns to an existing table for another activity use

Tags: android, sqlite

I have opened an SQLIte database with one single table and it has column for data (String names) and column for id (long id). This one belongs to MainActivity. 
The next thing I wanna do is to open, in the same table, additional columns (String item) and (int price). This columns will belong to ChildActivity.

My two questions are:

1. Which way to choose - to open two more columns or to store both item and price values in one String[] array and then put it in one column. It should be mentioned that I will need price for separate calculations as well. In my understanding, putting in two separate columns would make it easy to access price. But will id then differ for column item and column price? If yes, it can all become messed up.
   If I will have both in one String[] array would it be easy to get price (int) value out for calculations?
2. Since I will access ChildActivity from MainActivity by choosing names and getting their id(s), when I will open new columns in already existing table will id for item and price differ from what I already have? If no, then does it mean that I have to open new table with new column(s) for item and price and they will have their own id?

I am a new guy in android environment and in studing SQLite, so could you please provide me  with easiest but efficient solution and be tolerant if my questions seems very simple.

Thank you in advance.

TABLE

```
       MainActivity   =====|====>            ChildActivity
                           |
Column id     Column names | Column (id ?)   Column item  Column (id ?)   Column price
1             A            |                 item_1                       100
2             B            |                 item_2                       300
3             C            |                 item_3                       500
4             D            |                 item_4                       200
5             E            |                 item_5                       100


Another way to do

TABLE

Column id     Column names   Column (id ?)   Column item and price    
1             A                              String[] item_and_price = {"item_1", 100}     
2             B                              String[] item_and_price = {"item_2", 300}     
3             C                              String[] item_and_price = {"item_3", 500}     
4             D                              String[] item_and_price = {"item_1", 200}     
5             E                              String[] item_and_price = {"item_1", 100}
```

Comment: string[] is not convinient to store or to query. I would advise against it.

Comment: ids are for row, not for columns

Comment: a table is not related to an activity.

Comment: storing the both item and price in the same column will kill the purpose of using database.

Comment: I want item and price to be chained. Because in other way, I afraid, it will all messed up. The actual situation is that I have two EditText fields in one item and price Dialog.

Comment: when put them in database they will have different id's. Am I correct? cv.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ITEM, content);
db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE, null, cv);

Comment: cv_2.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_PRICE, content);

Comment: Since I will have interactions between Activitties probably it will be better to have another TABLE to write item and price separate from what I already have. Please advise.

Comment: to njzk. I want one TABLE to be used for storing both activities data.

Answer (score 0):

When started to work close with SQLite have found that njzk2 and Yaqub Ahmad are correct. string[] is not convenient to store or to query. ids belong to row and to solve my issue of having item and price chained I have to create new table with column for item and column for price, each entry will have id for both. Hope this information will help for beginners.